# List of all DataAnnotation Error Strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want to create multiple .resx resource files (for localization) with all the default error strings in it. So far I found FieldMustBeDate, FieldMustBeNumeric, PropertyValueInvalid and PropertyValueRequired error string names during my search (They work all right). But there are more, like regex, email, min-max length etc...? I guess the [MVC source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Cors/Properties/SRResources.resx) code could help to find them all out, if I could understand where to look :)

Anyways, how can I access to all these error message strings?

Comment: Did you ever find the resource Name used by the MaxLenght attribute?

Comment: I guess there are not any. The only ones I found were the ones I mentioned on the question. And I found them all in other SO questions.